# Pandas python, what is the workbook encoding type?

Tags: python, pandas, mandrill

I am new to python and also to the pandas library in Python. The documentation is not well described and they didn't explain it well. I want to save the dataframe as an excel format and **in the memory** and I have found the following explanation:
[[Pandas excel to the memory]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-memory)

I need an explanation about `workbook`. The value of this variable is encoded, how can I see the real value of this variable? How to decode it? what should be return value for it?

EDITED:

How to pass it into the content of attachment in Mandrill api.
`https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.python.html`

This is my attachment part for [excel extension](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) :

```
'attachments': [
            {
                'content': content,
                'name': 'fraud_report.xlsx',
                'type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }
```

I am not able to open the excel file and all the time i'am getteing an error from Microsoft excel which said `the file format is not valid!...`
Any help can be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the explanation i paste the example from your link here again:

```
# Safe import for either Python 2.x or 3.x
try:
    from io import BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from cStringIO import StringIO as BytesIO

bio = BytesIO()

# By setting the 'engine' in the ExcelWriter constructor.
writer = ExcelWriter(bio, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Save the workbook
writer.save()

# Seek to the beginning and read to copy the workbook to a variable in memory
bio.seek(0)
workbook = bio.read()
```

The method `writer.save()` saves the data in **BytesIO** (`bio`) instead of Excel file. It means, that the variable `bio` stores the bytes codes of the excel file.

The method `bio.seek(0)` sets the current position (for reading, writing,...) of `bio` to **0**. So that you can read the data of `bio` from beginning with the next method `bio.read()`.

The variable `workbook` store the bytes string of the excel file (or excel workbook). If you read a excel file in byte mode, you will get the same data. Or you can write it in a excel file:

```
with open("my_excel_file.xlsx", "wb") as f:
   f.write(workbook)
```

To read data from `bio` and store in a **DataFrame** you don't need `bio.read()`:

```
bio.seek(0)
df = pd.read_excel(bio, "Sheet1", engine="xlrd")
```

---

*For your question about using of **mandrill**:*

In the example of **mandrill** you see:

```
{'attachments': [{'content': 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl',
                      'name': 'myfile.txt',
                      'type': 'text/plain'}],...
```

The documentation writes about it too:

> content: the content of the attachment as a base64-encoded string

You should encode `workbook` in base64 and use it for sending

```
import base64
content = base64.b64encode(workbook)
```

*P/S: `workbook` and `content` have the type `bytes`. May be you need to convert `content` to `str` before sending.*

```
{'attachments': [{'content': content.decode('utf-8'),
                          'name': 'myfile.xlsx',
                          'type': 'text/plain'}],...
```

*Add: if file is excel then you should change `type` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`*

Comment: I would like to add I am using `mandrillapp` in `https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.python.html` to send a message, so i don't want to use write method. I would like to store only in a variable and then send it to the `content` of attachment. do u have other suggestion for me?

Comment: I don't know about `mandrillapp`. But do you want to send the content of a `DataFrame` or of a `Excel File`?

Comment: Mandrill is only accept the variable and then building the file by its own. This app doesn't read the file. so i cannot pass it a file.

Comment: Do you want to use `mandrillapp` to send mail with **mailchimp** with the excel file as attachment?

Comment: yes, exactly! I would , as I understood is not possible to pass the file, so I want to read it and then create excel with help of Mandril. Beside, in your explanation, `df = pd.read_excel(bio, "Sheet1", engine="xlrd")` should be a replacement for `workbook = bio.read()`. It is not clear, how to read and what are the previous lines then.

Comment: You can encode the variable `workbook` in base64 and use it for sending. I have updated my answer for that.

Comment: Do u mean for convert to str,  `1) workbook = bio.read()`,   `2)newStringThing = workbook.decode(encoding='UTF-8')`,`3)content = base64.b64encode(newStringThing)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115122/discussion-between-maryam-pashmi-and-julivico).